# What is this garage pipe contraption and can I use it to shut down outside water?

Tags: plumbing

[image: Strange Garage Piping Contraption]

I'm actually asking because I was searching my garage for some way to turn off external water for the winter and this was the closest thing that I could find. Unfortunately I have no idea what it does or why and would love it if anyone could shed some light!  The bottom of that vertical pipe stack dissapears into the concrete below the garage.  The horizontal pipe thing is unconnected (at least in the garage.  No idea what is happening in the wall.

Edit: As requested, adding a close up of the gauge on top:

[image: Gauge on Top]

Comment: The horizontal pipe looks like either black steel for gas, or galvanized pipe for water.  The vertical could be water main.  Can't tell if that's a pressure reducing valve, or backflow (above lower ball valve).

Comment: Really hard to tell from the picture, but it looks to me like a set of hookups for a boiler system.  Gas pipe horizontally on the wall, and the vertical pipe looks like it has a pressure relief valve between the cutoffs and a pressure gauge on the top.

Comment: horizontal wall pipe is for gas as the "Tee" connector mid-span looks like a sediment trap and the left end you can just see a gas valve.

Comment: does the gauge at top of vertical pipe show a reading? And does it change if the valves are opened or closed?

Comment: I think the water heater right next to it might be a clue. The fact that the vertical pipe is insulated is another clue...

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense about the horizontal wall pipe.  The builder said that he originally built the house for gas but ended up never connecting it.

Comment: The guage at the top does show a reading but I confess I'm just a bit nervous about throwing the valves on and off without knowing what they're up to.  I'll add a picture of the guage.

Comment: Added Gauge Pic

Comment: So yeah, the hookups for boiler system make a lot of sense then.  Unused since the contractor switched over to electric midway through house build.  It all becomes clear, thanks!

Comment: Down near the bottom of the vertical pipe, it looks like there's a check valve. Between the valves, it looks like there's a pressure regulator. Both of those fittings should have an arrow stamped into them. Which way does the arrow point, up or down? Just above the upper valve, it looks like there's something on the wall behind the pipe. Is it a device to fasten the pipe to the wall, or does the pipe tee there and enter the wall?